# Golang: how to use interface{} type to insert a value into the middle of a slice?

Tags: reflection, go

I'm having difficulty getting my head around the usage of `interface{}` types with Go.

In this instance I have a function which inserts a value into the middle of a slice somewhere. It looks like this:

```
type mystruct {
    a, b, c int
}

func insert(ar []mystruct, val mystruct, i int) []mystruct {
    l := len(ar)
    if l == cap(ar) {
        tmp := make([]mystruct, l + 1, (l * 2) + 1)
        copy(tmp, ar[0:i])
        copy(tmp[i+1:], ar[i:])
        ar = tmp
    } else {
        ar = ar[0:l+1]
        copy(ar[i+1:], ar[i:])
    }
    ar[i] = val

    return ar
}
```

I'd like for that function to be able to accept `interface{}` for both `ar` and `val` so that I could pass it a slice and value of any type and it would perform the insert without complaint.

From what I have read so far I believe this should be done with the `reflect` package. I have read the Rules of Reflection and various tutorials on reflection and `interface{}`, but I'm not sure how to approach this. I'd like to minimize overhead as much as possible, I understand reflection is going to slow the code down a bit but what is the most efficient way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't try to write this kind of functions in Go. They are complicated to write, slow in execution and usually not nearly as useful as you think.

Comment: @FUZxxl, what do you mean, don't do it? I have to perform this action - it is for a real-world application, written in Go and it needs to do exactly this. I could do it without `interface{}` like above every time, but it would mean copy and pasting and modifying that code hundreds of times. What do you suggest?

Comment: @Alasdair you could make a generic function that only stores `interface{}`, and when you read from this list convert it to whatever it is you've stored into it. that's for example how Go's standard library's linked list package works.

Comment: @Alasdair Is the type in the slice different each time? Inserting a value into the middle of a slice is an O(*n*) operation; you might want to consider a different data structure when this is a very common operation.

Answer (score 1):

The whole "grow if at capactiy" code is unnecessary; use the built-in `append` – it does exactly that for you.

Change the signature to:

```
func insert(ar interface{}, val interface{}, i int) interface{}
```

Then check that `ar` is a slice and that the element type of `ar` is the same type as `val`:

```
at, vt := reflect.TypeOf(ar), reflect.Typeof(val)

if at.Kind() != reflect.Slice {
    panic(fmt.Sprintf("expected slice, got %T", at))
}

if at.Elem() != vt {
    panic("first argument must be a slice of the second argument's type")
}
```

After type validation, get a hold of some `reflect.Value`s:

```
av, vv := reflect.ValueOf(ar), reflect.ValueOf(val)
```

And get moving stuff around using e.g:

- `(reflect.Value).Index(int)` to access element of the slice.
- `reflect.Copy` to copy to and from slices à la built-in `copy`
- `reflect.Append` to append to a slice `Value`
- `(reflect.Value).Set(reflect.Value)` to set the value of a settable element (something you got out of a slice, for instance).
- `reflect.Append` or `reflect.AppendSlice` to append to a slice à la built-in `append`.

Once you have your final `reflect.Value` representing the result slice; return it as an `interface{}` like this:

```
return result.Interface()
```

Comment: The reason I didn't use append is because I am assuming that it would slow down the growth seeing as I need to copy it in two parts: everything before the insert index and eveything after. Append would copy all of it, which I would then copy again. I was attempting to avoid two copies of the entire slice. Though I'm not certain this is more efficient as append may be faster if it is not compiled from Go source - but in theory what I am doing is faster than using append.